# Determine if SSL certificate is self signed using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, certificate, x509

I am trying to determine if an SSL certificate is self signed or not. Currently I have the following code which compares the issuer CN and the subject CN and if they are the same, marks the result as self signed.

```
with open(cert_file, "r") as f: 
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, f.read())

result = {
    'subject': dict(x509.get_subject().get_components()),
    'issuer': dict(x509.get_issuer().get_components()),
    'serialNumber': x509.get_serial_number(),
    'version': x509.get_version(),
    'notBefore': datetime.strptime(x509.get_notBefore(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ'),
    'notAfter': datetime.strptime(x509.get_notAfter(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ'),
}

extensions = (x509.get_extension(i) for i in range(x509.get_extension_count()))
extension_data = {e.get_short_name(): str(e) for e in extensions}
result.update(extension_data)

if result['issuer']['CN'] == result['subject']['CN']:
    result.update({'self-signed': True})
else:
    result.update({'self-signed': False})
```

This comparison is very simplistic, but works in a lot of cases. I'm not trying to verify SSL certs or reimplement OpenSSL. How can I make this better and be roughly 95% sure if a certificate is self signed or not?

My one requirement is that I would like to do this in Python and not call other processes or use shell commands.

Comment: You also need to make sure the signature is valid...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm not too concerned with the validity of the cert, or are you saying that is part of determining if the cert is self signed?

Comment: Probably this should help? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93162/how-to-know-if-certificate-is-self-signed

Comment: A certificate is self-signed when it has been signed with its own private key. Verify the digital signature of the certificate with the public key embedded in the certificate. Comparing subject and issuer strings will work in most cases, but if you want to guarantee 100%, you must verify the signature

Comment: You can verify the cert in a context. `crypto.X509StoreContext(store, cert).verify_certificate()` raises an `X509StoreContextError` with code 18, depth 0 and message `self-signed certificate` on self signed certs.

Comment: @hoefling This seems like the direction I should be looking in. I'm going to play around with it and see if I can get it to work. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenSSL [definition of self-signed](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/doc/man3/X509_get_extension_flags.pod) is:

> The subject and issuer names match and extension values imply it is self signed.

The [code that determines whether a cert is self-signed](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e6716f2bb4d9588044820f29a7ced0f06789d6ef/crypto/x509/v3_purp.c#L473) is:

```
/* Return 1 is a certificate is self signed */
static int cert_self_signed(X509 *x)
{
    X509_check_purpose(x, -1, 0);
    if (x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_SS)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

And the [code that sets `EXFLAG_SS`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e6716f2bb4d9588044820f29a7ced0f06789d6ef/crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c#L108):

```
/* Does subject name match issuer ? */
if (!X509_NAME_cmp(X509_get_subject_name(x), X509_get_issuer_name(x))) {
    x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_SI;
    /* If SKID matches AKID also indicate self signed */
    if (X509_check_akid(x, x->akid) == X509_V_OK &&
        !ku_reject(x, KU_KEY_CERT_SIGN))
        x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_SS;
}
```

So basically three things to check:

- The subject name and the issuer name must match
- The subject key identifier and the authority key identifier must match
- The cert must contain a key usage extension with the `KU_KEY_CERT_SIGN` bit set

You are already comparing the subject name and the issuer name. The next important thing to do would be to compare the SKID and the AKID. After a cursory glance at pyopenssl it doesn't look like it provides a way to check this, so if you want a pure Python solution you might have to extend the library. However even the code you have would probably cover you in 95% of cases you said you wanted it to cover.

Comment: You also need to verify the signature of the certificate with its public key. [RFC5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1) states _"The signature on a self-signed certificate is generated with the private key associated with the certificate's subject public key.  (This proves that the issuer possesses both the public and private keys.) In this case, the subject and authority key identifiers would be identical, but only the subject key identifier is needed for certification path building._

Comment: Seem OpenSSL is strict checking KU_KEY_CERT_SIGN, but reading RFC5280 it is not clear that it is mandatory, and a certificate could be considered  "self-signed" without key usage extension and  keyCertSig bit. See dcooper16 comment in this thread https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1418#issuecomment-238316454

Comment: That issue contains a debate over X509 compliance and is still open, after 3 years... Don't know if the OP should strive to make his code more conformant than OpenSSL.

Comment: IIRC OpenSSL does not actually check the signature of self-signed certs because "it adds no security"

Comment: @pedrofb - I think it depends on the type of certificate - end entity (`CA:FALSE`) or Certificate Authority (`CA:TRUE`). If `CA:TRUE`, then the some bits of KU and EKU can be set; otherwise another combination of KU and EKU bits can be set. One thing's for certain, end entity certs cannot assert `keyCertSign` and `cRLSign` bits because end entity certs cannot sign other certificates.